# Netlogo add the average distance information on patches from the patch 3 -3

Tags: distance, netlogo, patch

I would like to know how to design this.

All patches will compare their own distance from the patch [3 -3] with the average distance. So they realize that they are closer or far from the average distance.

Answer (score 2):

```
globals [ref-patch av-dist]

to setup
  ca
  set av-dist mean [distance patch 3 -3] of patches
  demo
end

to demo
  ask patches [
    if distance patch 3 -3 < av-dist [
      set pcolor red
    ]
  ]
end
```

Comment: The `ref-patch` global is unused.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would put everything in a patch reporter like this:

`to-report closer-than-average?
  report distance patch 3 -3 < mean [distance patch -3] of patches
end`

Then you can

`ask one-of patches [show closer-than-average?]`

or

`ask patches with [closer-than-average?] [set pcolor blue]`

etc.